I cannot find my pnpm file after containerizing my NodeJS application
I am new to Docker and NodeJS, I have an app I am trying to containerize, but when I try to load the app in the Docker environment it throws this error:
app-1      | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
app-1      |   throw err;
app-1      |   ^
app-1      | 
app-1      | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/pnpm'
app-1      |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
app-1      |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
app-1      |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
app-1      |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
app-1      |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
app-1      |   requireStack: []
app-1      | }
app-1      | 
app-1      | Node.js v20.13.1

Below are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files:
Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.13.1-bookworm-slim as base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y openssl

RUN npm install -g npm@latest && \
 npm install -g pnpm  && \
 pnpm install && pnpm --version && \
    echo "PNPM Path: $(which pnpm)"

COPY . .

RUN which pnpm

RUN pnpx prisma generate --schema=src/prisma/schema.prisma

RUN pnpm run build

# Production stage
FROM node:20.13.1-bookworm-slim as final

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/package.json ./



CMD ["pnpm", "run", "dev"]

docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"  
    env_file:
       - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules  
    depends_on:
      - db  
    

  db:
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d ${DB_NAME}" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  pgadmin:
      image: dpage/pgadmin4
      environment:
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgamin.org
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      ports:  
        - "5040:80"

volumes:
  db-data:

# DB_HOST=localhost
# DB_PORT=5432
# DB_NAME=shuttle
# DB_USER=postgres
# DB_PASSWORD=2030

At first when I got this error, I thought it was probably how my pnpm was being installed in the docker environment, so I tried to add in the commands to install pnpm when starting the container, like this: CMD ["npm install pnpm && pnpm install && pnpm run dev"] to the CMD` line in the dockerfile, but it did not help, all it did was run the install and gave me this:
app-1      | 
app-1      | removed 25 packages, and changed 74 packages in 54s
app-1      | 
app-1      | 22 packages are looking for funding
app-1      |   run `npm fund` for details
app-1 exited with code 0

Which is not what I want. I have to tried to update my docker-compose.yml file to include the commands but it still does the same thing. I read somewhere that I should not be putting so much commands to the CMD or command script, but removing everything brought me back to the initial error message.
What am I doing wrong?

It seems you never run pnpm install inside the build container, before copying node_modules into the production container?

The volumes: block you have hides pretty much everything in the image.  If you change the package.json file, you'll still get the old node_modules tree from the anonymous volume.  Does deleting the volumes: help?

@Bergi What do you mean exactly? Where should I put the command?

@DavidMaze you think i should not include the volumes block?

You should delete the volumes: block that hides the image's /usr/src/app directory, yes.  (But keep the volumes: for persistent storage in the db container.)

@DavidMaze it still didnt work

What worked for me was this:
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 build-essential openssl
ENV PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3

# Enable corepack for package management (including pnpm)
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@9.11.0 --activate

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Production dependencies fetch stage
FROM base as prod

# Copy only necessary files for installing dependencies
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* /usr/src/app/

# Install only production dependencies using pnpm
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile 

RUN pnpm fetch 

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .



Glad you fixed it! The answer will be more helpful to future readers if you can say what changed and why that helped.
